# 15.04, Wireless randomly have long delay

Tags: wireless, 15.04, realtek-wireless

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 with Wifi Driver RTL8723BE

When I ping Google, time randomly go over 10,000ms. (usually 15ms)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: does your router have a preamble setting?

Comment: @mchid I set with long preamble

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your preamble to short in your router settings. This will reduce the time for a faster response.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

It should fix these issues.